# How to achieve DataBinding of a code behind element?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, user-controls, custom-controls

I have the following scenario: I'm creating a card game, and as part of it, I want to create a UserControl to make the interface programming easier and better. I'm creating the following user control:

.cs

```
public partial class ChimeraUserControl : UserControl
{   
    private ChimeraViewModel Chimera { get; set; }

    public ChimeraUserControl(Chimera chimera)
    {
        this.Chimera = new ChimeraViewModel(chimera);
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

I want to be able to do two things: when using this user control, to be able to send a `Chimera` through binding, and also, to make all the texts and other elements to be binded to this `Chimera`. I've searched a lot, but didn't find nothing that satisfied me.

What do you guys think?

What I already tried to read:

http://dev-for-fun.blogspot.com/2008/06/wpf-example-create-usercontrol-and.html

[Binding from View-Model to View-Model of a child User Control in Silverlight? 2 sources - 1 target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467423/binding-from-view-model-to-view-model-of-a-child-user-control-in-silverlight-2)

And a lot of other pages, but none seemed straight-forward enough, and by hacking its codes I didn't find my problem's solution.

Comment: From the upvotes I'm getting I guess it is a real problem the lack of documentation to binding.

Comment: Add xaml or code behind where you're attempting to do desired stuff. It  will show problem more precisely.

Comment: Code behind is here. I'll add a piece of XAML later, though it isn't necessary IMO, since I couldn't do nothing there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, make `Chimera` a [Dependency Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) so it can participate in the binding system

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ChimeraProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("Chimera ", typeof(ChimeraViewModel), 
    typeof(ChimeraUserControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

public ChimeraViewModel Chimera 
{
    get { return (ChimeraViewModel)GetValue(ChimeraProperty ); }
    set { SetValue(ChimeraProperty, value); }
}
```

Second, you can reference your `Chimeria` property through a `RelativeSource` or `ElementName` binding

```
<UserControl x:Name="ChimeraViewRoot" ... >

    <StackPanel>
        <!-- ElementName Binding -->
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=ChimeraViewRoot, Path=Chimeria.Name}" />

        <!-- RelativeSource Binding -->
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ChimeraView}}, Path=Chimeria.Name}" />

    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

You can also just set the `DataContext` of the controls inside your `UserControl` to the `Chimera` property to make your binding syntax cleaner

```
<UserControl x:Name="ChimeraViewRoot" ... >
    <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ChimeraView}}, Path=Chimeria}" >

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />

    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

I usually do not suggest defining the `UserControl.DataContext` in your `UserControl` because that value is supposed to be passed in from whatever uses the `UserControl`. Setting in inside the `UserControl` can cause confusion later on when you're trying to figure out why a specific `UserControl` doesn't work with an expected `DataContext`.

---

Personally when I create a `ViewModel` that is supposed to go with a specific `UserControl`, I prefer to set a `DataTemplate` in the application so that all instances of my `ViewModel` get drawn with my custom `UserControl`. This means that I assuming the `UserControl.DataContext` will always be of a specific `ViewModel` type

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ChimeriaViewModel}">
    <local:ChimeriaView /> <!-- DataContext will always be ChimeriaViewModel -->
</DataTemplate>
```

This will use the `ChimeriaView` implicitly whenever the Visual Tree encounters an object of type `ChimeriaViewMmodel`.

For example, the following will render a `StackPanel` filled with `ChimeriaView` objects

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyListOfChimeriaViewModels}" />
```

Or to display a single object I'll usually use something like a `ContentControl`

```
<!-- Will get drawn using ChimeriaView due to DataTemplate defined above -->
<ContentControl Content="{Binding MyChimeriaViewModelProperty}" />
```

Also, by knowing the `DataContext` for the `ChimeriaView` is going to be an object of type `ChimeriaViewModel`, I would get rid of the `DependencyProperty` altogether

```
<UserControl>
    <StackPanel>
        <!-- I know the DataContext is ChimeriaViewModel -->
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />

    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now that is straight forward!

Comment: Question: I define a DataTemplate instead of a UserControl instead?

Comment: @Bruno I use `DataTemplates` and `UserControls` both depending on my needs. If it makes sense to group elements in a control of it's own, I'll use a `UserControl`. If it is something simple, or for a smaller scope, I'll use a `DataTemplate`. Also, place the `DataTemplate` wherever it makes sense to do so. If it is defining an application-wide template, put it in `Application.Resources`. If it's a user-control template, put it in `UserControl.Resources`.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest following things from whatever I can understand from your quest.

1. You should be making this a Custom control instead of UserControl.

> Have a look at following links for help -
>
> [Control Authoring Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025.aspx)
>
> http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/49802/Create-a-WPF-Custom-Control-Part-2
>
> Make `Chimera` a `DependencyProperty` to support `Binding` (as explained in SO link you have added and above articles).